# sql query return null but table has multiple record

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am running this query in CodeIgniter framework. code below

```
     $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_exam_marks');
    $this->db->where('examid','9');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    $s4 = $query->row();
```

this producer create a query like this 
SELECT * FROM `tbl_exam_marks` WHERE `examid` = '9'

but no row return from this.
while I run  the query on MySQL table it returns a row

Comment: what is output of  => echo $this->db->last_query(); ??

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl_exam_marks WHERE examid = '9'

Comment: How do you know, that the query returns no rows? How did you check "sql query return null"? thanks for some more input...

Answer (score 0):

try this code with `get_where` hope it will help you

```
$data = $this->db->get_where('tbl_exam_marks', array('examid' => 9))->row_array();
```

Comment: dude - his query is fine - what you show here is just an alternative - nothing more ...